# Find out target csv file name for a Spark DataFrame.write.csv() call

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

In a pyspark session when I do this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(file)
df.write.csv('output')
```

it creates a directory called `output` with a bunch of files, one of which is a target csv file with unpredictable name, example: `part-00006-80ba8022-33cb-4478-aab3-29f08efc160a-c000.csv`
Is there a way to know what the output file name is after the `.csv()` call?

Answer (score 0):

When you read a parquet file in the dataframe it will have some partitions as we are using distributed storage here. Similarly when you save that dataframe as an csv file it would get saved in an distributed manner based on the number of partitions that dataframe had.

The path that you provide at the time of writing the csv file would create a folder with that name is what happens and then you would have multiple partitions files inside that folder. Each file would have some portion of data  and when you combine all that partitions file you get the entire content of the csv file.

Also if you read that folder path then you would be able to see the entire content of the csv file. This is the default behaviour of how spark and distributed computing works.